# Update PGP key in self hosted apt repository

Tags: apt, gpg, nexus

We are using the `Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager` to host `apt` repositories. The `GPG` key of one of them has expired recently and needed to be updated. What I thought would be sufficient was to generate new key pairs (as [described](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/apt-repositories) in the official site docs), paste the new private key through the Nexus UI and new passphrase then `apt-key add` new public key on client system and all would be good to go. What happens instead is that `apt update` still says `NO_PUBKEY <old_id>`. I have no idea whatsoever where does the `apt` takes the information from now, that it misses the old key and does not "synchronize" the new key. I have also tried to delete contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` directory before calling the `apt update`. What am I missing?

EDIT:
All is run in clean docker, where only new key is added `apt-key add public.gpg.key` and new repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, `echo "deb <repo_url> bionic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: show us the apt conf, the source conf where you put the repository, mostly or lets say sometimes the kry has been fixed there

Comment: @djdomi I see what you mean. In the `sources.list` nothing is specified for the repository in `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. The nexus apt repository creates two folders. One is called `metadata` and one is called `packages`. In `metadata` folder the files `Release`, `InRelease` and `Release.gpg` are created. These are not automatically regenerated when the key is changed in the UI. To force the regeneration of these files, the folder has to be deleted and a package has to be uploaded. This will trigger the regeneration of the metadata folder with all the appropriate files in it. After this operation, the keys are working.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do like this:

1. update GPG private key in repo settings
2. delete `metadata/dists` subdirectory in the repo
3. run `apt-get update` on some client connected to the repo.

The metadata should be updated after this.