# Nexus Repository OSS: apt hosted repo gpg signing

Tags: apt, gpg, nexus

Nexus Repository OSS version: 3.63.0-01

We have created a hosted apt repository and we keep getting these messages on apt update:

```
E: Failed to fetch <apt-repo-url>/dists/jammy/InRelease  401  Unauthorized [IP: 10.20.179.21 8081]
E: The repository '<apt-repo-url> jammy InRelease' is not signed.
```

I've seen in [Update PGP key in self hosted apt repository](https://serverfault.com/questions/1089031/update-pgp-key-in-self-hosted-apt-repository) that you may delete the `metadata` directory, but we cannot see this directory in the web view.

Should we try another version or is there something we are missing?

Comment: Your server returns `401 Unauthorized`. Check your server configuration for any IP restrictions.

Comment: Correct. I added a conf file in /etc/apt/auth.conf.d/ (containing the respective credentials) and now I am getting a 500 Server Error. Will continue debugging.

Comment: Checked the `nexus.log` and found out that I had set a wrong pair of PGP private key and its pass phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an authorisation issue, as I had not added the repo credentials to `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/`. So it was never a signing issue. Also, the `metadata` directory was created after the first successful update by the apt client.